# Variety $V=\{(x,y)\in k^2\mid xy=1\}$ is connected

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $k$ be an infinite perfect field. Show that the variety
$$V=\{(x,y)\in k^2\mid xy=1\}$$
is connected of dimension $1$.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: *Hint*. It is even irreducible, because $xy-1 \in k[x,y]$ is prime.

Comment: And a reminder: the set of $\mathbb{R}$-points doesn't tell the whole story...